# Regex Search end of line and beginning of next line

Tags: python, regex

Trying to come up with a regex to search for keyword match at end of line and beginning of next line(if present)

I have tried below regex and does not seem to return desired result

```py
re.compile(fr"\s(?!^)(keyword1|keyword2|keyword3)\s*\$\n\r\((\w+\W+|W+\w+))", re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
```

My input for example is

```
sentence = """ This is my keyword
/n value"""
```

Output in above case should be keyword value

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your regex seems to be trying to match keyword1, keyword2 or keyword3 and the next line begins with /n, so how do you end up saying the output should be 'keyword value'. I think you need to re-specify precisely what a 'keyword match' is and what you are looking for at the start of the subsequent line (and are you saying the subsequent line is optional meaning the keyword might be at the end of the string and that's still a good match?).

Comment: What about this `(keyword\d*)\s*$\s*(\w+.*)`? https://regex101.com/r/frwd9Q/2.

Answer (score 1):

You could match the keyword (Or use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)) to match more keywords and take trailing tabs and spaces into account after the keyword and after matching a newline.

Using 2 capturing groups as in the pattern you tried:

```
(?<!\S)(keyword)[\t ]*\r?\n[\t ]*(\w+)(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is directly on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `(keyword)` Capture in **group 1** matching the keyword
- `[\t ]*` Match 0+ tabs or spaces
- `\r?\n` Match newline
- `[\t ]*` Match 0+ tabs or spaces
- `(\w+)` Capture **group 2** match 1+ word chars
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7dNuuu/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EviBhd)

For example:

```
import re

regex = r"(?<!\S)(keyword)[\t ]*\r?\n[\t ]*(\w+)(?!\S)"
test_str = (" This is my keyword\n"
    " value")

matches = re.search(regex, test_str)

if matches:
    print('{} {}'.format(matches.group(1), matches.group(2)))
```

Output

> keyword value

Answer (score 0):

How about `\b(keyword)\n(\w+)\b`?

```
\b(keyword)\n(\w+)\b

\b                      get a word boundary
  (keyword)             capture keyword (replace with whatever you want)
           \n           match a newline
             (\w+)      capture some word characters, one or more
                  \b    get a word boundary
```

Because `keyword` and `\w+` are in capture groups, you can reference them as you wish later in your code.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/XCiW1p/1)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, depending of the number of new lines that you might have, an expression similar to:

```
\b(keyword1|keyword2|keyword3)\b[r\n]{1,2}(\S+)
```

might be somewhat close and the `value` is in `\2`, you can make the first group non-captured, then:

```
\b(?:keyword1|keyword2|keyword3)\b[r\n]{1,2}(\S+)
```

`\1` is the `value`.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/NljPrh/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/NljPrh/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---